# Automatically generate Java classes source files when a file changes using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jooq

I'm working on a Java application whose build is currently done via Gradle. The application uses jOOQ, which provides a domain-specific language to construct queries from Java classes (source files) generated from a database schema. I'd like to regenerate these Java source files when the database schema changes. Could I do that using a Gradle task?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Etienne Studer's (from Gradle) third party Gradle plugin contribution [that is recommended by jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/), see:
https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#configuring-the-jooq-generation-task-to-participate-in-incremental-builds